# Continuous websocket traffic with SignalR

Tags: websocket, signalr

I've been using SignalR successfully for some time using serverSentEvents transport. I've just installed my application on Windows Server 2012 RC and now when I connect SignalR is using websockets (as you'd expect).

It appears to work OK except there is a continuous stream of websocket traffic between server and browser - about once a second it's sending about 90 bytes.
From the debugger window in Chrome, it looks like it's sending a connection upgrade request each time.

I am successfully receiving messages sent by the server, but I seem to be worse off than when using long polling.
The browser is Chrome version 19.0.1084.52.
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

This was down to my own stupidity - but I thought I'd answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

I had built the solution SignalR.Hosting.AspNet instead of SignalR.Hosting.AspNet45
So the method AcceptWebSocketRequest was throwing a NotSupportedException; because the client websocket upgrade failed, it just tried again about a second later.

I guess the client *could* show an error or something in this case to aid debugging.